# WSO2 Gouvernance Registry v4.1.1 on Tomcat v6

Tags: registry, tomcat6, wso2

I'm a new member on stackoverflow.

I try to deploy WSO2 Registry Governance v4.1.1 on Tomcat.

To do this, Is there a tutorial on the net :

http://opensource-soa.blogspot.fr/2009/03/deploying-wso2-registry-on-tomcat.html

when I finished his steps, I have an exception:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: instance already set
org.wso2.carbon.bridge.BridgeServlet.setInstance (BridgeServlet.java: 227)`

Which is obsolete as it is for WSO2 Registry 2.0.1 and structure of the project had changed.

Somebody had already do this operation ?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all ,You can use Wso2 Governance Registry product without deploying any application servers like tomcat. However, if you have strong requirement to deploy on tomcat, this the updated documentation for wso2greg-4.1.1.

[1]http://wso2.org/project/carbon/3.2.2/docs/admin_guide.html#webappmode

Thanks
Ajith

Comment: thank you very much.
this web page  is not referenced on google.

now, when I try to authentificate myself with : 
**Username: admin ; Password: admin**
I have this message : 
**Login failed! Please recheck Server URL and try again.**

There is a possibilitie other  for configure the parameters of authentification ?

Thank you in advance